# How should I structure code/files to avoid repeating time consuming calls to build a data structure?

Tags: python, code-structure

I am working on a word puzzle game solver that needs to determine whether or not some candidate word is valid. I am storing all of the valid words in a trie data structure, after they have been loaded from a text file. Building this trie (adding around 370,000 words to the trie) takes around 5 seconds on my computer.

The main part of my program takes an image of a puzzle (a codeword puzzle, to be specific), interprets the puzzle and solves it using a depth-first search. The problem I have right now is that building the trie takes 5 seconds and when a user wants to solve a new image, the trie is rebuilt each time, even though it never changes. The rest of the process, from loading the puzzle image to having a finished result, takes around 1 second, so it is unacceptable to wait 5 seconds to build a trie every time.

I am currently getting around this by partitioning my main script into sections to isolate the trie building code. This is done using `#%%` in the Spyder IDE, like you can do in Matlab, or having a new cell in a Jupyter notebook.

Here is how I have things structured right now:

```
# codeword_solver_trie.py

class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}
        self.is_word = False
        
        
class WordDictionary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode()      

    def addWord(self, word):
        current_node = self.root
        for character in word:
            current_node = current_node.children.setdefault(character, TrieNode())
        current_node.is_word = True
        
    def search(self, word):
        def dfs(node, index):
            if index == len(word):
                return node.is_word
               
            if word[index] == ".":
                for child in node.children.values():
                    if dfs(child, index+1):
                        return True
                    
            if word[index] in node.children:
                return dfs(node.children[word[index]], index+1)
            
            return False
        return dfs(self.root, 0)
```

I have another file where the main processing occurs. It contains this function:

```
def build_word_dictionary_trie(words):
    print("Building trie...")
    word_trie = WordDictionary()
    for word in words:
        word_trie.addWord(word)
    return word_trie
```

The relevant part of the main script is as follows:

```
word_list_fpath = "data/words_alpha.txt"
all_words = load_all_words(word_list_fpath)

# Build the trie from the word list
word_trie = build_word_dictionary_trie(all_words)

#%% (this separates the execution of the code above from the code below)

# Load image from file and convert from BGR to RGB
original_img = cv2.imread(f"data/codeword_images/{img_num}.jpg")
# ...
```

How can I build this trie exactly once and have the user be able to re-run the processing an arbitrary number of times without resorting to this hack of sectioning the code with `#%%`?

Comment: `build_word_dictionary_trie()` should be internal to WordDictionary and `WordDictionary.__init__()` should accept a path or all_words

Comment: At the moment though, once `word_trie` is defined, why do you need to or can't seem to avoid rebuilding it?

Comment: Thanks for the advice on moving the code inside the class. To answer your question, I am defining `word_trie` in my main script above the image processing etc. While I'm developing this, if I want to try another image, I simply edit the image file path and re-run the script. This means the code for building the trie is executed again. Checking for the existence of a variable in a try/except feels hacky as well. It feels like I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Sounds like you want to serialize your trie object. There is a module called pickle in the standard library you may have a look at.

Comment: oh, I see. So the file is re-run for each word rather than run once prompting for new words.  In that case, once the word_trie is constructed, you might look to pickle it then load back the pickle on each run

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The file is run once for each image. The image contains a word puzzle where letters are encoded using numbers, and solving the correct number-letter pairs is the aim of the puzzle. A list of encoded words is extracted from the puzzle image and a solver, which uses a depth-first search, substitutes letters for numbers, then checks whether or not the resulting (partially)-decoded words exist in the trie. I tried saving the constructed trie using pickle, but it actually takes longer to load it than it does to construct it again. I also tried using `marshal` and `json` to no avail.